# Vue: Waiting for props before mounted is run

Tags: vue.js

I have component, ShopCart.vue (code below), that is receiving props from the parent.  One of those props is `cartItems`.  I am running a function on the cartItems in `mounted()` but to make sure the props were ready, I put them in `Vue.nextTick`, which I saw as a solution here on StackOverflow.  That seemed to resolve the issue but I noticed it wasn't reliable and there were instances where the cartItems would be empty when the function was ready.  To test this, I put them in a setTimeout for 3 seconds and then the cartItems had 20 passed items, so I know it's working..it's just running too quickly.  How can I resolve this to ensure the props are ready in this component?

*Part of the ShopCart.vue*

`export default {`

```
data() {
    return {
        dataLoaded: false,
        modalType: null,
        orderNotes: null, 
        test: null,
        expireTimes: {

        }
    }
},
props: {
        cartItems:  {type: Array},
        cart:       {type: Object},
        customer:   {type: Object}
    },
mounted() {
    let vm = this;      

    Vue.nextTick(() => {
        vm.cartItems.forEach((item, index) => {
            Vue.set(vm.expireTimes, item.item_id, "")
            this.checkItemExpiry(item.expire_at, item.item_id)

        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Is the `cartItems` coming from an async call? (i.e. API call)

Comment: @FranciscoHanna yes, on the parent component, it's coming from an API call

Answer (score 13):

@Francisco Hanna's answer will work for you, but you can avoid a watcher (which is consuming resources) if you simply use `v-if` to render the `shopCart` component only after any cartItems exist:

in the parent component:

```
<shop-cart :cartItems="cartItems" v-if="cartItems.length"></shop-cart>
```

Comment: this is actually very smart idea

Answer (score 5):

You could try using [Vue's watch property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) over the `cartItems` prop so when it changes you can then process it, like so:

```
watch: {
    cartItems(newVal) {
        newVal.forEach((item, index) => {
            Vue.set(vm.expireTimes, item.item_id, "")
            this.checkItemExpiry(item.expire_at, item.item_id)
        });
    }
}
```

Make sure to pass an empty array if the `cartItems` is not ready in the parent component, or validate with something like `if(newVal){ ... }` before the `forEach` iteration.

Comment: awesome, thanks.  Just not sure if I should then remove the `mounted()` logic entirely then?

Comment: @jjoan Yes, you can remove the mounted method safely.

Comment: @jjoan Accept this answer if it solved your problem please!

Answer (score 0):

Vue.nextTick is usually used when updating a reactive component and you want to use the DOM with the updated value. Vue.nextTick is not intended for async operations, as the time for the async operation is not known in advanced.

Your best bet is to use a v-if when disaplaying the content. This will also allow you to use v-else and maybe show a preloader.

Answer (score 0):

`this._props.cartItems` can be reached inside `mounted()` in vue2